# Refresh Access Table from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an excel vba program that pushes two sets of data in a parent-child configuration from an excel sheet into an access database. The connection and pushing works, but I've run into a problem where if the last parent record was deleted in the database, the primary key and foreign key don't match. This is because the SQL query I have pulls the largest number in my autonumber primary key field, and even if I execute this query after inserting the parent data, it still pulls back the same primary key as before. This has me in a position where I need to requery the access database to figure out the latest entry's primary key. However, entries don't show up in the database until the table has been refreshed.

So my question is how do I refresh the access table so the latest entry will show up in my query?

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I solved this problem by closing the connection to the parent table and reopening it before querying the primary key again.